# How to overlay one div over another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I hover my mouse over a div with id one, dialog box appears, but the div with id three moves to the right.

I want the dialog box to appear over div with id three without it moving to right.

**HTML PAGE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{
width:300px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid #000000;
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
}
#one,#three{
position:relative;
}
#two,#four{
margin:0;
padding:0;
left:334px;
top:100px;
background-color:#3B3B3B;
border:none;
width:200px;
height:100px;
display:none;
position:relative;
left:14px;
}
#triangleone,#triangletwo{
margin:0;
padding:0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-color:transparent;
border-top: 8px solid transparent;
border-right: 14px solid #3B3B3B;
border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
top:35px;
display:none;
position:relative;

}
#dialogboxone,#dialogboxtwo{
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:214px;
display:none;
border:none;
}
</style>
<script>
var timer;
function showDialogBox(idOne,idTwo,idThree){
var firstSideBar=document.getElementById(idOne);
var secondSideBar=document.getElementById(idTwo);
var dialogBox=document.getElementById(idThree);
timer=setTimeout(function(){
firstSideBar.style.display="block";
secondSideBar.style.display="block";
dialogBox.style.display="block";
},800);
}
function hideDialogBox(idOne,idTwo,idThree){
clearTimeout(timer);
var firstSideBar=document.getElementById(idOne);
var secondSideBar=document.getElementById(idTwo);
var dialogBox=document.getElementById(idThree);
firstSideBar.style.display="none";
secondSideBar.style.display="none";
dialogBox.style.display="none";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one" onmouseover="showDialogBox('two','triangleone','dialogboxone')" onmouseout=hideDialogBox('two','triangleone','dialogboxone')></div>
<div id="dialogboxone">
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="triangleone"></div>
</div>
<div id="three" onmouseover="showDialogBox('four','triangletwo','dialogboxtwo')" onmouseout="hideDialogBox('four','triangletwo','dialogboxtwo')"></div>
<div id="dialogboxtwo">
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="triangletwo"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just as advice, please try to avoid to style your HTML in your HTML file. CSS is the better way :)

Comment: It's always a good idea to provide a jsfiddle link for your problem. on another note, you use float on your divs thats why when you hover over your dialogbox box its taken out of the document flow therefore the floated element moves up to take its spot. From what I am seeing you probably want to get rid of float and use absolute positioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a wrapper to position the dialogboxes against:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one"></div>

    <div id="dialogone"></div>
</div>
```

Then you'll need to position the wrapper relatively, and position them to your liking (eg. with `float`). The dialog can be positioned absolutely, for example: `position: absolute; left: 100%` to position them just outside the wrapper to the right.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/z290t9xa/)

Note: please try to format your code a bit more readable, with indents and spaces... Whenyouwriteinenglishyoualsousespaces,doyou?